# How to create PHP hex timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, hex

I have to make timestamp in php to hex timestamp in php. Problem is, I cannt find way how to do it. Guess it will be some easy function. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a hex epoch timestamp by calling the current timestamp with time() and then using the dexhex function to convert it to hex:

```
$hextime = dechex(time());
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php